# Is the empty matrix $M$ ($m \times n$) with $m$ or $n$ equal to zero in RREF ? Does it posses every matrix property one would wish?

Tags: linear-algebra, definition

> Is the empty matrix $M$ ($m \times n$) with $m$ or $n$ equal to zero in RREF ?

Reading a proof in Linear Algebra induction starts off by proving $P(n)$ holds for $n=0$, where $P(n)$ is the statement: "The matrix $M$ ($m \times n$) has a reduced row echelon form".

However, no introduction has been given to the empty matrix $A$. **Is the empty matrix considered to have every matrix property one would wish, like inverse, RREF-form etc. ?**

Comment: Sorry, I read empty matrix but thought of the zero matrix.

Comment: No problem. I wonder why no one has a comment on this.

Comment: I have now posted a revised answer. Sorry again for misreading your question.

Comment: Good point. They are really empty. [Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_(mathematics)#Empty_matrices) is a reference. Then I suppose what you surmise is true and any statement is true for the empty matrix. Sorry for any confusion I caused.

Comment: I would say that if we have to decide if an empty matrix is in RREF or not, then it is. Because if it is not, then this means you can reduce it further; but can you?